# Assign or Add a Quote Product to a revised quote in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I´m writing a plugin that assigns or adds a quote product to a revised quote. When revising a quote, this one will be closed and a new one is created in draft mode. The new quote has the same quotenumber but contains no quote products from previous closed one! Everything goes well but I´m facing a security principal exception while assigning the quote product to the quote in my code. May be I´m thinking wrong with my logic. Should I assign the product to the quote or the quote product to the quote? I´m creating a new quote product, assign the product from previous quote to it, then I assign the quote product to the quote, am I right?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please, show your piece of code where you're assingning a quote product.
Showing the error message also would be very helpfull.
And what do you mean saying Assign?
Because assing is the action of changing owner of a record.
To add a quote product to a qoute you should make a N:1 relation from quote product to a quote.

Comment: Thank you Grigory, I solved it. The problem was the messege event in the plugin registration tool. I seted it the update, but correct is create, because crm creates a new quote and close the old one.